# editing content pages and configuration hangs (spinning donut)

Tags: magento2, cms, admin-panel, cms-pages, magento2.3

This has happened to me twice now: I get the site installed, I get the template installed, and eventually I start customizing the site and the content pages in the backend stop loading.  The first time, I couldn't edit the default theme for the global site.  The current time, I can't load pages to edit.

The flow looks something like this:

1. go to edit some content
   [image: go to edit some content]
2. go to edit a page
   [image: go to edit a page]
3. page appears to load, but the donut doesn't go away
   [image: page appears to load, but the donut doesn't go away]

Any suggestions?  I can't continue to update the theme without this working. :(

[image: It looks like some resources are missing.]

Comment: Just started getting the same for no reason. Did you ever get anywhere?

Comment: Could you do F12, and check in network if you have 500 error ?
if yes then can you post the error message ?

Comment: @Mohamed23gharbi, thanks for the hint.  It looks like resources are missing.